# Spring security, x509 and switching user

Tags: spring, security, certificate, x509

Here's the scenario.  I have a WAR that is connected to using SSL from an Eclipse RCP client using an X.509 certificate.  After I verified that I have the certificate I want to retrieve the user details (ie. implement the loadUserByUsername) and read the userId from the request header (supplied by the client) and NOT use the supplied DN from the certificate.  Is this possible?  Essentially I trust the caller to supply me with the userId that I should use in my Spring security context.
My Spring configuration currently looks like this and works for the standard case of extracting the DN from the X.509 cert and loading the user.

```
<security:http>
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" requires-channel="https" />
  <security:x509 subject-principal-regex="^(.*?)$" />
</security:http>
<security:authentication-manager>
  <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService" />
</security:authentication-manager>
```

I need this to support the scenario of PKI client (user1) -> PKI service A -> PKI service B (run service B as user1).*